# React App works perfectly on localhost, but errors out on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, redux

Very frustrating errors today. I've spent the entire day trying to debug my small application that works perfectly on my localhost, but errors out on heroku occasionally.

If I refresh the page several times, I can achieve the login. But it takes 2-3 refreshes.

The two errors I get when logging in a user are -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exercise_name' of undefined
```

And

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

Now I basically know what the issue is. I must not have my props when I initially try to map over them. One of the props is an array of exercises, with one of the keys as 'exercise_name.' I'm guessing it has to do with the speed I receive the from local host, compared to heroku's ajax calls.

Here is my issue,

I do not know which component this is coming from since, I use exercise_name in 4 components. Heroku has line numbers, but they are of no help since it doesn't point to anything in my application and I can't drop debuggers in heroku like I can on my machine here.

I've tried setting default props in mapStateToProps like so -

```
allExercises: state.entities.exercise || []
```

Did not work.

Ive tried wrapping things in conditionals in my components. Hasn't worked.

The following four components use exercise_name. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

I understand the following is a lot of code. I would be completely content with an answer letting me know how to find which lines of code are producing these errors on heroku, or how to debug on heroku in general.

component 1

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import SetResultContainer from '../setresult/create_setresult_container';

class ExerciseIndex extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputVal: '',
      active: 'FIRST',
      name: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputVal: e.target.value })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestAllExercises();
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ inputVal: e.currentTarget.attributes.value.value})
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    let newActive = this.state.active === 'FIRST' ? 'SECOND' : null
    let allExercises = this.props.allExercises;
    let selected;
    let name;
    if (allExercises) {
      allExercises.forEach(exercise => {
        if (exercise.exercise_name === this.state.inputVal) {
          selected = exercise,
          name = exercise.exercise_name
        }
      })
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (!name) {
      this.setState({inputVal: 'Invalid Input, Please try Again'})
      return 'Invalid Input'
    }
    this.props.requestExercise(selected)
    this.setState({inputVal: '', active: newActive, name: name})
    this.props.requestAllExercises();
  }


  render() {


    let allExercises = this.props.allExercises || [{ exercise_name: '' }]

      let match = allExercises.map((exercise) => {
        if (this.state.inputVal === '') return [];
        let matched = [];
        if (this.state.inputVal.length > 0) {
          for (var j = 0; j < this.state.inputVal.length; j++) {
            matched = [];
            if (exercise.exercise_name.slice(0, j + 1).toUpperCase() === this.state.inputVal.slice(0, j + 1).toUpperCase()) {
              matched.push(<li onClick={this.handleClick}
                               value={exercise.exercise_name}
                               className="workout-auto-li"
                               key={exercise.id}>{exercise.exercise_name}</li>);
            }
          }
        } else {
            matched.push(<li onClick={this.handleClick}
                             value={exercise.exercise_name}
                             className="workout-auto-li"
                             key={exercise.id}>{exercise.exercise_name}</li>)
        }
        return matched;
      });


    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.allExercises ? (
          <div>
            {this.state.active === 'FIRST' ? (
              <div className="exercise-main-div">
                <div className="exercise-second-div">
                  <label className="exercise-label">
                    <h3>Add an Exercise for {this.props.liftname}</h3>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.inputVal}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      className="exercise-input"
                      />
                  </label>
                  <ul className="exercise-ul">
                    {match}
                  </ul>
                  <button className="new-exercise-button"
                    onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add Exercise</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : this.state.active === 'SECOND' ? (
              <SetResultContainer user={this.props.user}
                exercises={this.props.exercises}
                exercise={this.state.name}
                liftname={this.props.liftname}/>
            ) : null }
          </div>
        ) : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ExerciseIndex);
```

component 2

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import values from 'lodash/values'
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

class Leaderboard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { exercise: null }
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestAllUsers();
    this.props.requestAllExercises();
  }

  handleUpdate(property) {
    return e => this.setState({ [property]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const members = this.props.members.map(member => {
      return <li className="members-list" key={member.id + 1}>{member.username}</li>
    })

    const memberId = {}
    this.props.members.map(member => {
      memberId[member.username] = member
    })

    const membersSetResults = {}
    const membersLiftMaxes = {}
    const completedMemberExercises = []
    const completedExercises = {}

    this.props.members.map(member => {

      if (member.workouts) {
        let workouts = values(member.workouts)
        for (var i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++) {
          let workoutResult = workouts[i].setresults
          let results = values(workoutResult)
          if (membersSetResults[member.username]) {
            membersSetResults[member.username].unshift(results)
          } else {
            membersSetResults[member.username] = [results];
          }
        }
      }
    })

    Object.keys(membersSetResults).map(member => {
      let setResults = membersSetResults[member]
      membersLiftMaxes[member] = {}
      for (var i = 0; i < setResults.length; i++) {
        let sets = setResults[i]
        for (var j = 0; j < sets.length; j++) {
          let currentExercise = this.props.allExercises[sets[j].exercise_id]
          let exercise = currentExercise.exercise_name

          if (completedMemberExercises.indexOf(exercise) < 0 && currentExercise.ex_type === 'lift') {
            completedMemberExercises.push(exercise)
          }

          if (completedExercises[exercise]) {
            completedExercises[exercise] += 1
          } else if (!completedExercises[exercise]) {
            completedExercises[exercise] = 1
          }

          if (currentExercise.ex_type === 'lift') {
            if (membersLiftMaxes[member][exercise]) {
              if(membersLiftMaxes[member][exercise] < sets[j].weight_lifted) {
                membersLiftMaxes[member][exercise] = sets[j].weight_lifted
              }
            } else if (!membersLiftMaxes[member][exercise]) {
                membersLiftMaxes[member][exercise] = sets[j].weight_lifted
            }
          }
        }
       }
     })


       const PieChart = {
         datasets: [{
           data: Object.values(completedExercises),
           backgroundColor: [
             '#2D4262',
             '#363237',
             '#73605B',
             '#D09683',
             '#F1F3CE',
             '#1E656D',
             '#00293C',
             '#F0810F',
             '#75B1A9',
           ],
         }],

         labels: Object.keys(completedExercises)
       };



     let exerciseDropdown = completedMemberExercises.map((exercise, idx) => {
       return <option key={idx} value={exercise}>{exercise}</option>
     })

     let sorted = [];
     const memberAndMax = {}
     Object.keys(membersLiftMaxes).map(member => {
       if (this.state.exercise) {
         let exerciseMax = membersLiftMaxes[member][this.state.exercise]

         if(!memberAndMax[this.state.exercise]){
           memberAndMax[this.state.exercise] = []
           memberAndMax[this.state.exercise].push([member, exerciseMax])
         } else if (memberAndMax[this.state.exercise]) {
           memberAndMax[this.state.exercise].push([member, exerciseMax])
         }

         memberAndMax[this.state.exercise].map(max => {
           if (sorted.indexOf(max) < 0) {
             if (max[1] > 0) {
               sorted.push(max)
             }
           }
         })

         sorted.sort((a, b) => {
           return a[1] - b[1]
         })
       }
     })


     let maxLis = sorted.reverse().map((user) => {

       if (memberId[user[0]].id === this.props.cu.id) {
         return <li className='userPresent' key={memberId[user[0]].id}>
                            <p className="members-list-p">{user[0]}</p>
                            <p className="members-list-p-two">{user[1]}</p></li>
       } else {
         return <li className='members-list' key={memberId[user[0]].id}>
                            <p className="members-list-p">{user[0]}</p>
                            <p className="members-list-p-two">{user[1]}</p></li>
       }

     })




    return (

      <div className='main-leaderboard'>
        <div className='lb-reset-div'>
          <button className='lb-reset-button' onClick={() => this.setState({exercise: null})}>Reset</button>
          <select className='leaderboard-dropdown' onChange={this.handleUpdate('exercise')}>
            <option>Please Select</option>
            {exerciseDropdown}
          </select>
        </div>
        {(this.state.exercise) ? (
          <div className='lb-ul-div'>
            <h3 className='selected-ex-title'>{this.state.exercise}</h3>
            <ul className='leaderboard-ul'>
              <li className="members-list"><p className="members-list-p">Name</p>
              <p className="members-list-p-two">Max (lbs)</p></li>
              {maxLis}
            </ul>
          </div>
        ): (!this.state.exercise) ? (
          <div className='lb-ul-div'>
            <h3 className='selected-ex-title'>Leaderboard</h3>
            <ul className='leaderboard-ul'>
              {members}
            </ul>
          </div>
        ): null}
          <div className='pie-chart-div-lb'>
            <h3 className='pie-chart-header'>What the World's Doing</h3>
            <Pie circumfrence={300} data={PieChart}/>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default withRouter(Leaderboard);
```

component 3

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import values from 'lodash/values';
import { Line, Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

class SearchBestWorkouts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputVal: '',
      name: '',
      active: '',
      result: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestAllExercises();
    this.setState({active: 'FIRST'})
  }


  handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e)
    this.setState({ inputVal: e.target.value })
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ inputVal: e.currentTarget.attributes.value.value})
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    let newActive = this.state.active === 'FIRST' ? 'SECOND' : 'FIRST'
    let allExercises = values(this.props.exercises);

    let selected;
    let name;
    if (newActive === 'SECOND') {
      allExercises.forEach(exercise => {
        if (exercise.exercise_name === this.state.inputVal) {
          selected = exercise,
          name = exercise.exercise_name
        }
      })
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!name) {
        this.setState({inputVal: 'Invalid Input, Please try Again'})
        return 'Invalid Input'
      }

      this.setState({inputVal: '', active: newActive, name: name})
      this.props.requestAllExercises();
    } else if (newActive === 'FIRST') {
      this.setState({inputVal: '', active: newActive, name: '' })
    }

  }

  render () {

    let allWorkouts = this.props.allWorkouts;
    let exercises = this.props.exercises;

    let setResults = allWorkouts.map(workout => {
      return values(workout.setresults)
    })

    let mergedSets = [].concat.apply([], setResults)

    const allResults = {}
    const exerciseTypes = {}
    const completedExercises = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < mergedSets.length; i++) {
      let set = mergedSets[i];
      let exercise = exercises[set.exercise_id]
      let name = exercise.exercise_name
      let bodypart = exercise.bodypart

      if (exerciseTypes[bodypart]) {
        exerciseTypes[bodypart] += 1
      } else if (!exerciseTypes[bodypart]) {
        exerciseTypes[bodypart] = 1
      }

      if (exercise.ex_type === 'lift') {
        if (!allResults[name]) {
          allResults[name] = { labels: [],
                               datasets: [{
                                 label: 'Weight over Time',
                                 backgroundColor: '#2988BC',
                                 borderColor: '#2F496E',
                                 data: [],
                              }],
                            };
        }


        if (completedExercises[name] < (set.weight_lifted)) {
          completedExercises[name] = set.weight_lifted
        } else if (!completedExercises[name]) {
          completedExercises[name] = set.weight_lifted
        }

        allResults[name].labels.push(allResults[name].labels.length + 1)
        allResults[name].datasets[0].data.unshift(set.weight_lifted)
      }


    }


    const PieChart = {
      datasets: [{
        data: Object.values(exerciseTypes),
        backgroundColor: [
          '#2D4262', '#363237', '#73605B', '#D09683'
        ],
      }],

      labels: Object.keys(exerciseTypes)
    };




    const best = Object.keys(completedExercises).map((exercise) => {
      if (this.state.inputVal === '') return [];
      let bests = [];
      if (this.state.inputVal.length > 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.state.inputVal.length; j++) {
          bests = [];
          if (exercise.slice(0, j + 1).toUpperCase() === this.state.inputVal.slice(0, j + 1).toUpperCase()) {
            bests.push(<li onClick={this.handleClick}
                             value={exercise}
                             className="best-lift-li"
                             key={exercise.id}>{exercise}</li>);
          }
        }
      } else {
        bests.push(<li onClick={this.handleClick}
                         value={exercise}
                         className="best-lift-li"
                         key={exercise.id}>{exercise}</li>)
      }
      return bests;
    });

    return (
     <div>
       {this.state.active === 'FIRST' ? (
         <div className="best-lift-div">
           <div className='best-lift-div-two'>
             <h3 className="best-lift-title">Personal Records</h3>
             <div className='best-lift-input-div'>
               <input type="text" value={this.state.inputVal}
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                 className="best-lift"
                 placeholder="Enter an Exercise"
                 />
             </div>
             <ul className='best-lift-ul'>
               {best}
             </ul>
             <button className='best-lift-button' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Best Lift</button>
           </div>


         </div>
       ) : this.state.active === 'SECOND' ? (
         <div className="best-lift-div">
           <div className='best-lift-div-two'>
             <h3 className="best-lift-title">
               {this.state.name}: {completedExercises[this.state.name]}</h3>
             <div className='chart-background'>
               <Line width={250} height={200} data={allResults[this.state.name]}/>
             </div>
             <button className='best-lift-button' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Back</button>
           </div>
           <div className='best-lift-div-three'>
             <h3 className="best-lift-title">Workout Analysis</h3>
             <div className='pie-chart-background'>
               <Pie circumfrence={100} data={PieChart} />
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       ) : null}
     </div>
    )
  }
}


export default withRouter(SearchBestWorkouts)
```

component 4

```
import React from 'react';
import values from 'lodash/values'
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class WorkoutShow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.deleteWorkout(this.props.selectedWorkout).then(
      () => {
        this.props.requestUser(this.props.match.params.userId)
      }
    )
    this.props.toggleParent();
  }

  render () {
    const setArray = values(this.props.selectedWorkout.setresults)
    const exercises = this.props.exercises
    const results = setArray.map((result, idx) => {
      if (result.workout_id === this.props.selectedWorkout.id) {
        return <li key={result.id} className='workout-show-li'>
                   <p className='workout-title'><p>Set {idx + 1}: </p><p>{exercises[result.exercise_id].exercise_name}</p></p>
                   <ul>
                     {result.weight_lifted ? (
                       <li className='workout-result-li'><p className='workout-result-li'>Weight:</p>{result.weight_lifted}{result.weight_unit}</li>
                     ) : null}
                     {result.reps ? (
                       <li className='workout-result-li'><p className='workout-result-li'>Reps:</p>{result.reps}</li>
                     ) : null}
                     {result.distance ? (
                       <li className='workout-result-li'><p className='workout-result-li'>Distance:</p>{result.distance}{result.distance_unit}</li>
                     ) : null}
                     {result.hour || result.min || result.sec ? (
                       <li className='workout-result-li'><p className='workout-result-li'>Duration:</p>
                         <div className='dur-format'>
                           {result.hour ? (
                             <p className='dur-result-hour'>{result.hour}:</p>
                           ) : null}
                           {result.min ? (
                             <p className='dur-result'>{result.min}:</p>
                           ) : null}
                           {result.sec ? (
                             <p className='dur-result'>{result.sec}</p>
                           ) : null}
                         </div>
                       </li>
                     ) : null }
                   </ul>
                  </li>
      }
    })

    return (
      <div className="workout-show-main">
        <h3 className="workout-show-title">{this.props.selectedWorkout.name}
          <button className='remove-workout-button' onClick={this.handleClick}>DELETE</button></h3>
          <InfiniteScroll>
            <ul className="workout-show-ul">
             {results}
            </ul>
         </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default withRouter(WorkoutShow);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being on a server introduces delays in fetching of data, and things that 
 work perfectly locally don't work as well on the server.

The major culprit is your code, which is making assumptions about return values. For example

```
const setArray = values(this.props.selectedWorkout.setresults)
const exercises = this.props.exercises
const results = setArray.map((result, idx) => {
```

Line 3 of this block blindly assumes that `setArray` is defined and an array. You need to add checks in at every step, or provide default values (see the end of the first line below)

```
const setArray = values(this.props.selectedWorkout.setresults) || []
const exercises = this.props.exercises
const results = setArray.map((result, idx) => {
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to add what I call 'defensive code' to check return values and handle missing data without barfing.

You can also add try..catch blocks to trao any errors that your defensive code doesn't handle.

It will take some time, but it's worth upgrading your methodology to include this as standard practice if you want to write good code

Comment: I planted default values in every possible spot and kept testing. One of them finally got rid of the errors. Thank you.

Comment: Good work, it's a good exercise in nailing those bugs and making your code robust